# PostCSS Autoprefixer Setup in an Astro Project

Tags: postcss, autoprefixer, astrojs

#### What I'm trying to achieve

Set up automated autoprefixer on `npm run build` of an Astro project on all global stylesheets and component scoped styling to support other browsers and older browsers (up to about 2016).

#### My build

- Astro v1.9.1
- CSS compiled via SCSS
- A few Astro integrations (imagetools, prefetch, compress, NetlifyCMS are the only ones I think could have any relevance to this issue)

#### Steps I've taken

1. Built out an Astro project that uses both global styles in the `/src/styles` folder as well as scoped styling in Astro components
2. Ran `npm install autoprefixer`
3. Created a `.postcss.config.cjs` with the following code [based on the docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#postcss):

   ```
   module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    };
   ```
4. Ran `npm run build`

#### What I expected

- For my CSS to be compiled with different vendor prefixes for browser support
- My main test of adding `text-size-adjust: 100%;` in `src/styles/global.css` to cause a `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;` to be added to my compiled CSS in `dist/assets` (the build folder)

#### What else I have tried

- Creating a `.postcssrc.json` which contains

```
{
  "map": true,
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {}
  }
}
```

- Adding extra Vite configuration to my `astro.config.mjs`:

```
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

export default defineConfig({
  vite: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        autoprefixer({}), // add options if needed
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

- Adding some browserslist conditions to my `package.json` to set conditions for the autoprefixing

```
{
   "browserslist": [
       "last 2 versions",
       "not dead",
       "> 0.2%"
     ]
}
```

#### Result & Conclusion

- However I am **still not getting autoprefixing to occur in my project**
- I'm also struggling to find answers online or in the Astro Discord server - which is making me wonder: **Are people not really using autoprefixer anymore? How are people supporting other vendors and older browsers?**

Comment: Is the dot at the start of `.postcss.config.cjs` a typo? Because I think it shouldn't be there.Got it working with `sass` loading config as `.json` or `.cjs`, fell free to ask about my setup even though i wasn't really doing anything special.

I too was quite surprised to see little to no discussion about this topic

Comment: Oh very good point, that was not a typo I actually named the file that... Thanks for pointing that out! I have actually got autoprefixer to work properly in another project but will be revisiting this soon (as certain properties weren't being prefixed for older browsers which I often require).

Comment: It does work, but the CSS needs to be part of the Astro process flow in order for it to get processed. Try putting `text-size-adjust: 100%;` inside of an `.astro` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this template https://github.com/lightrix/astro-starter-template It has autoprefixer, cssnano, compression and all the things you need.